# Can you launch a app C# so it doesn't need the .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I am using *windows 10* and I do want to run my application on a windows 7 computer but I am not allowed to download the .NET framework, is there a way which I don't need to install the .NET framework on windows 7?

Comment: Windows 7 has .Net 3.5 preinstalled

Comment: Have you tried running the app on Windows 7? If Windows Update is installed (which it should be) then you *should* have up to date .Net already on the Windows 7 PC.

Comment: You could also precompile you app using .NET Native https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn584397(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It purely depends on what type of app. If you are developing console apps, use .NET Core and then the published app is self contained and does not rely on .NET Framework at all. http://dot.net

Answer (score 7):

You have to use one of the versions before 4.0 if you want it to work right away.
Windows 7 has versions 1 through 3.5 installed by default.

Downgrade the app and rebuild for .net 3.5

https://superuser.com/a/298030

Comment: How do you do that?