# Can you launch a app C# so it doesn't need the .NET and you don't downgrade the .NET version

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I asked this before but if i downgrade to .NET 3.5 I am not able to do some things with the windows form application I get errors because some things that have been added in later versions are not in the version that I am using.
I am making the application for Windows 7.

Link to previous: [Can you launch a app C# so it doesn't need the .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38477212/can-you-launch-a-app-c-sharp-so-it-doesnt-need-the-net)

Comment: What are the actual errors you get? Obviously if you depend on a later version of the framework you will need to run against that version.

Comment: Do you mean you want to deploy e.g. a .NET 4.6 winforms application against a machine that only has .NET 3.5?

Answer (score 0):

As C# is essentialy a human-readable version of .NET's intermediate language (IL) you cannot run an application created using C# without .NET *runtime* installed.
You don't need to downgrade anything - just change target version to 3.5. However, you'll have to stick to features of 3.5 and below in that case.
If you want to use 4.0+ - just make an installer for your app which installs .NET 4.0 runtime alongside.

P.S.
I personally really doubt that there is noticable count of boxes running Windows 7 without at least .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Just include the required Framework for your application in the Installer. They should be able to run side-by-side.